# Searching for users in AD using wildcarts/regexp?

Tags: c#, active-directory

I've figured out how to search the AD, however in order to get a a search result, my search has to be exact. I can't just do exact.
The problem is that I have to look up a user based on the telephone number, and those can be written in just about as many formats as there are people typing them.
My input is always an MSISDN, that is just the numbers, no spaces or extra characters in between, the fields in the AD is anything but that simple.

How can I search for such numbers without retrieving all users and do the scan in software.

For the example, I'm looking at the fields "mobile" and "telephoneNumber".

The numbers in the AD could for instance be "+45 12 34 56 78" or "(555) 1234", the latter hardly qualifies as a valid MSISDN though, but the idea is the same, all sorts of insanity seen from a computers perspective.
If I look up all users, I can generate the MSISDN by just removing all non digits, but I doubt an Enterprise is happy if I start dumping their entire AD everytime I need to find a number.

Sample code:

```
        String domain = "example.com";
        String msisdn = "4512345678";

        // create your domain context
        PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, domain);

        DirectorySearcher ds = new DirectorySearcher(ctx.ConnectedServer);

        ds.Filter = String.Format("(mobile={0})", msisdn);

        ds.PropertiesToLoad.Add("cn");
        ds.PropertiesToLoad.Add("sn");
        ds.PropertiesToLoad.Add("name");
        ds.PropertiesToLoad.Add("mail");
        ds.PropertiesToLoad.Add("mobile");
        ds.PropertiesToLoad.Add("telephoneNumber");

        foreach (SearchResult de in ds.FindAll())
        {
            Console.WriteLine("");
            foreach (String key in de.Properties.PropertyNames)
            {

                Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", key.PadRight(30, '.'), de.Properties[key].Count);
                int i = 1;
                foreach (String prop in de.Properties[key])
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", (String.Format("[{0}]", (i++)).PadLeft(30, ' ')), prop);
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine("");
        }
```

Comment: One option I've found that solves the problem, but it NOT elegant in any shape or form, is to parse the search string and insert wild card characters between each digit. MSISDN 4512345678 becomes the search string "*4*5*1*2*3*4*5*6*7*8*", or in my case "(mobile=*4*5*1*2*3*4*5*6*7*8*)". However if I start sending a few hundred of those off every second, I'm certain I'll have the sysadmin breathing down my neck, or worse, in very short order.

Answer (score 2):

You can put wildcards into your filter.  I have a similar program where I search the names to output phone numbers.

I filter thus:

```
static SearchResultCollection GetUsers(string target)
    {
        DirectoryEntry domain = new DirectoryEntry(<removed fqdn>);
        DirectorySearcher searcher = new DirectorySearcher(domain);
        searcher.Filter = "(&(objectClass=User)(displayName=*" + target + "*))";
        searcher.Sort = new SortOption("displayName", SortDirection.Ascending);
        return searcher.FindAll();
    }
```

Comment: But that doesn't quite work with what I have, the value in the AD is the partial or fragmented one, where I have the full value.

Comment: Well then your AD is terrible.  Kidding...  But do you have control over the AD at all?  There should be a process in place when users are added to have a standardized phone number.

Comment: Is the AD large?  Will your program be run often?  Are you trying to go back through and "fix" AD with this program or offer a phonelist type ondemand app that users can use?  How many different kinds of phone numbers are there in the AD (do the users put whatever they want, or admins from a few countries have different procedures, etc etc)?

Comment: I'm producing a third party application that needs to load users based on their phone number or their sip address.

Comment: The sizes of the AD will vary greatly, as will the frequency of my lookups. Of course I'll be cashing the data for some time, but in a dynamic environment thee are limits to how long I can go between these updates. I'll have little to no control over the format employed in the AD, national differences will play havoc on any attempt to try to enforce it. See my answer above, adding some qualifiers to the search, such as the ObjectClass, have meant that it is now fairly quick, cashing should reduce the load over time.